# How to get difference(in hours) between two timestamp in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get difference(in hours) between two timestamp in google bigquery;
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run below and you will see an idea to use

```
SELECT 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS timestamp_now, 
  TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) AS timestamp_start_of_day, 
  FLOOR((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()))/1000000/3600) AS diff_in_hours
```

see more for [Date and time functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions) and [Mathematical functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#mathfunctions)

Answer (score 11):

Using StandardSQL

```
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(timestamp_expression1, timestamp_expression2, HOUR)
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_diff